# Updating a form input name value after a $scope.$watch is triggered

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, angularjs-scope

I am using AngularJS 1.4. I have a form input element and I'm trying to set the name attribute dynamically.

```
<input type="email" name="{{ctrl.name}}" class="form-control" id="email" ng-minlength="5" required>
```

The `name` attribute is assigned as expected, as long as `name` is declared and assigned when the controller runs. I need it to work, however, after the controller detects a change to a parameter using `$scope.$watch`...

```
function FormFieldCtrlFtn($scope, $log) {
    var vm = this;    
    vm.name = ''; // works if I provide a name here

    $scope.$watch(function(scope) {
      return (vm.obj);
    }, function(newval, oldval) {
      if(newval) {
        vm.name = newval.name; // need it to work when the name is updated here
        $log.info('name: ' + vm.name);
      }
    });
}
```

Even though the `$scope.$watch` is trigged and the `vm.name` variable is assigned to a valid value, this is not being detected in my form. Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to watch a specific variable of your scope, I would recommand changing:

```
$scope.$watch(function(scope) {
    ...
});
```

To:

```
$scope.$watch('varYouAreWatching', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    ...
});
```

Where `varYouAreWatching` is the variable you want to watch.

---

[Here is a JSFiddle that may inspire you](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/47tn544j/)

Comment: Whatever OP is try is valid `$watcher` expression, as watcher can be a function.. but the only thing I'd suspect is, if OP wants to put a watch on whole object then he should be make it as `deep watcher` to detect changes over `vm.obj`

Comment: You can watch a scope variable using the function, it's a nicer way to decouple the controller from the variable (see here.. https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2852-understanding-how-to-use-scope-watch-with-controller-as-in-angularjs.htm). As I mentioned though the problem is not that the watch isn't being triggered. It is triggered but the change is not being detected in the form.